# Some users (groups) cannot be deleted when using NIS to manage users in CentOS 7.5 cluster

Tags: linux, users, nis

The cluster master and computing nodes are using CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core). File `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contains

```
passwd: files nis sss
shadow: files nis sss
group: files nis sss
```

The output of `getent passwd -s nis` includes

```
u2:$1$GE2edQgf$UyXuGspuf5uwbp.zK91aH0:9002:9002::/data/home/geou2:/bin/csh
u3:$1$Ddytc7s0$5yPBahgmfVyaqC0.Bur1.1:9003:9003::/data/home/geou3:/bin/csh
u1:$1$3Z52ZIDu$Od.rfOebsXRxI.nrBut1G1:9001:9001::/data/home/geou1:/bin/csh
```

The output of `ypcat passwd` also includes

```
u2:$1$GE2edQgf$UyXuGspuf5uwbp.zK91aH0:9002:9002::/data/home/geou2:/bin/csh
u3:$1$Ddytc7s0$5yPBahgmfVyaqC0.Bur1.1:9003:9003::/data/home/geou3:/bin/csh
u1:$1$3Z52ZIDu$Od.rfOebsXRxI.nrBut1G1:9001:9001::/data/home/geou1:/bin/csh
```

I can use `su` to switch into these users:

```bash
$su u1
Password.
mkdir: cannot create directory '/data': Permission denied
Attempting to create directory /data/home/u1/perl5
mkdir /data: Permission denied at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/local/lib.pm line 269.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
[u1@mu01 /]$
```

But deleting and creating a user with the same name results in the following error:

```bash
# userdel u1
userdel: Unable to remove u1 from /etc/passwd 
# useradd u1
useradd: user u1 already exists
```

There are no such users in `/etc/{passwd, shadow}`. (There are some corresponding groups where this is also the case)

The computing nodes can't log in to the above users:

```bash
[user@cu01 ~]$ su u1
su: user u1 does not exist
```

Executing:

```bash
makedbm -u passwd.byname
makedbm -u passwd.byuid
makedbm -u group.byname
makedbm -u group.byuid
```

None of the above users (groups) appear.

Since I need to install some commercial software, the user name and group name must be preset.

How can I delete these users and groups? Thanks for your help!

Tried `cd /var/yp/; make`, no luck.

Comment: Where is your NIS Master Server ? You should Delete the user there , not at the client.

Comment: @Prem thanks for your reply, all operations are performed on the master server.

Comment: In general , there may be some text files where the users are listed & NIS "make" Process will generate the DataBases. You could look into those text files & Delete the unwanted users. If necessary , you could update the text files with the users required by the Commercial tools

Comment: @Prem According to what I found, those files include passwd, shadow and group in /etc, but those strange users and groups did appear here.

Comment: did not appear here, sorry for the typo.

Comment: [[1]] Those files are "Static" files , which are always there. When NIS is used , `/etc/nsswitch.conf` says `passwd: files nis sss` which means "use those Static files first , if user not found then try NIS , if user still not found then try SSS". [[2]] Ok , now NIS itself has a "DataBase" of users which will be generated through some Dynamic `make` files or Shell Scripts. Those Dynamic `make` files or Shell Scripts will contain Details of those unwanted users. You might have to check & trace the Source Code of the `make` Process to locate the text files which are getting loaded into your NIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Prem's constructive comments.

I tried using `strace -o stypcat ypcat passwd` to figure out where `ypcat` was getting those usernames from and found that there were some `socket` and `connect` system calls pointing to another IP.

I logged into that IP (representing the management node of the other cluster), and those users appeared in `/etc/passwd` on that machine. I also found that the results for `domainname` were the same for both clusters.

It seems that the NIS of our cluster's management node treats another cluster's management node as its parent node.

Comment: Finally, I stoped the NIS server of the old cluster. It works.